# How to retry Uppy (using XHR plugin) requests failed due to JWT token expired error

Tags: reactjs, uppy

Currently, I am using the Uppy library to upload files in react using the XHR plugin. Sometimes while uploading files the JWT token gets expired and the upload request fails.

Answer (score 0):

try catch the error of the api call, in catch block refresh the jwt token, then recursive call the same function again, this time with new jwt token -> should pass